# DataGridView Autogeneratecolumns as TextBox instead of label

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, autogeneratecolumn

How can I have a datagridview that will autogenerate a textbox instead of a label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't.  You could inherit from a gridview and implement it yourself.  It could look something like this:

```
Public Class MyGrid
Inherits GridView


Private Sub MyGrid_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Me.RowDataBound
  If Me.AutoGenerateColumns = True Then
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For Each c As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            Dim tb As New TextBox()
            tb.Text = c.Text
            c.Controls.Clear()
            c.Controls.Add(tb)
        Next
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For the record it doesnt need to overload the class, if its just for a single problem you can just handle dgv.RowDataBound.

Thousand thanks.